# How to load .class files in java when classes are related?

Tags: java, class, classloader

I am trying to load a set of .class files from a specific path (package) using java class loader. The problem is: when one of these classes is related to a latter class or a class in another package, the class loader throws NoClassDefFoundError. How to solve this problem?
Here is my code

```
public ArrayList<Class<?>> readFiles(String nomeFile) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

           File f = new File(nomeFile);
           String[] files = f.list();
           for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) {
            Class<?> mycls;
               String fileName = files[i];
               String fnm=nomeFile+"/"+fileName;//file canonical name.class
               ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               try {
                   InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fnm);

                   byte [] buff = new byte[4096];
                   while (true) {
                       int c = in.read(buff);
                       if (c == -1) break;
                       out.write(buff, 0, c);
                   }
                   mycls  = defineClass(null, out.toByteArray(), 0, out.toByteArray().length);
                   System.out.println(mycls.getCanonicalName()+" class is loaded");
                    classes.add(mycls) ;


               }
           }
            return classes;

       }
```

Comment: Does this error happen from inside `defineClass` or on the line after it? Maybe you can define the other dependent classes before calling `resolveClass` ?

Comment: But if all you want to do is load from a special directory, why not just instantiate a normal URLClassloader configured appropriately?

Comment: The error happens from inside defineclass, I cannot define related classes first

Comment: Using URLClassloader doesnot solve this problem

Comment: Why not? How are you using it? URLClassloader can certainly load classes that depend on other classes.

Comment: Here is my code using URLClassloader and it gives classnotfoundexeption

Comment: public ArrayList<Class<?>> readFiles(String nomeFile) throws  ClassNotFoundException, MalformedURLException {
File f = new File(nomeFile);String[] files = f.list();
 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
if (files[i].endsWith(".class")) {
Class<?> mycls;
String fileName = files[i];String fnm=nomeFile+"/"+fileName;      
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();         
URL[] urls = new java.net.URL[]{url};
 ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);mycls = cl.loadClass(fileName); System.out.println(mycls.getCanonicalName()+" class is loaded");
classes.add(mycls) ; }}return classes;

Comment: No, I mean, don't write any code for this, just load the class using a URLClassloader. No method `readFiles` of such. `urlClassloader.loadClass` takes care of all that.

Comment: Yes, it was usefull and solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: As an addendum, when you enter a situation where you truly need a custom `ClassLoader`, you have to override the `findClass` method to return a `Class` on demand. Then, the linkage will succeed.